# Separation of php

Tags: php

This is a php file that displays the detail of a product (using product id).

```
<?php require 'config/config.php'; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
    //Get all details from the products table for the product selected 
    $sql = "SELECT productid, productsku, productname, productimage WHERE productid = \"" . $connect->real_escape_string($_GET['id']) . "\" LIMIT 0,1";
    $result = $connect->query($sql);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

    extract($row);
    echo $productname;
    echo '<img src=../lbsystem/'.$productimage.' width="210" height="240">';
    echo $productname; 
    echo $productsku; 
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

I have separated html from the php and have them in two different folders.

Like, folderA / code.php

```
    <?php
    require 'config/config.php'; ?>
    //Get all details from the products table for the product selected 
    $sql = "SELECT productid, productsku, productname, productimage WHERE productid = \"" . $connect->real_escape_string($_GET['id']) . "\" LIMIT 0,1";
    $result = $connect->query($sql);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

    extract($row);
    echo $productname;
    echo '<img src=../lbbosystem/'.$productimage.' width="210" height="240">';
    echo $productname; 
    echo $lbproductsku; 
    ?>
```

and folderB / productdetails.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

How do I get them together to produce a display using the product id ?. Please help.

Comment: `<body><?php include 'folderA/code.php'; ?></body>`? or were you looking for a templating system?

Comment: @castis, no I wasn't looking into templating system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Folder hierarchy :**

```
root/
  |----index.php
  |----folderA
  |       |----code.php
  |----folderB
  |       |----productdetails.html
```

**Code.php**

```
 <?php
    require 'config/config.php'; ?>
    //Get all details from the products table for the product selected 
    $sql = "SELECT productid, productsku, productname, productimage WHERE productid = \"" . $connect->real_escape_string($_GET['id']) . "\" LIMIT 0,1";
    $result = $connect->query($sql);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

    extract($row);
    echo $productname;
    echo '<img src=../lbbosystem/'.$productimage.' width="210" height="240">';
    echo $productname; 
    echo $lbproductsku; 
    ?>
```

**Productdetails.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
        [content]
</body>
</html>
```

**Index.php**

```
<?php

ob_start();
include_once("folderA/code.php");
$codes = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$html=file_get_contents('folder/productdetails.html');
$html_with_code=str_replace("[content]", $codes, $html);

echo $html_with_code;

?>
```

Comment: seems good, let me give it a go. Thanks, will get back after I try out.

Comment: thank you, it worked great. Now, I can separate the php code from the html markup language. The index.php combines both php and html for one single page (productdisplay) but what if i have more than one page?.

Comment: I just answered your question but this is not a good method for combining php and html or splitting. I recommend MVC system for this issue. Good Luck.

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for a templating system you should have a look into Smarty (http://www.smarty.net/)

Code will look like something like this

```
require 'config/config.php'; 
require 'smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php';
//Get all details from the products table for the product selected 
$sql = "SELECT productid, productsku, productname, productimage WHERE productid = \"" . $connect->real_escape_string($_GET['id']) . "\" LIMIT 0,1";
$result = $connect->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

extract($row);
$smarty = new Smarty();
$smarty->assign("productname", $productname);
$smarty->assign("productimage", $productimage);
$smarty->assign("lbproductsku", $lbproductsku); 
$smarty->display("template.tpl");
```

And template.tpl will be something like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    {$productname}<br />
    <img src="{$productimage}" />
    {$lbproductsku}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: PHPTAL is less ugly but it's already been stated that the OP is **not** looking for a templating system.